# How to resolve JNDI conflict between Jetty and OpenEJB?

Tags: maven, jetty, openejb, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm running Jetty (from Maven) with OpenEJB inside. The problem is that they conflict through JNDI context. The problem was explained some time ago by [Stephen Connolly](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2010/03/openejb-jetty-and-maven-transaction.html) with a solution. The solution looks rather outdated (it's for Jetty 6.x, while I'm using Jetty 7.x) and not very clear for me. Could someone explain whether it's possible at all to run Jetty and OpenEJB together? Would be great to see an example.

Comment: Any improvement regarding this?

Comment: @Sessizlik no progress so far, unfortunately :(

Comment: The principle is the same though the dependencies have changed. I'm not actively using OpenEJB in my current job so I have not needed to update this.